# How to create a uint256 in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

How can I create a uint256 data type in Postgres? It looks like they only support up to 8 bytes for integers natively.

They offer decimal and numeric types with user-specified precision. For my app, the values are money, so I would assume I would use numeric over decimal, or does that not matter?

`NUMERIC(precision, scale)`

So would I use `NUMERIC(78, 0)`? (2^256 is 78 digits) Or do I need to do `NUMERIC(155, 0)` and force it to always be >= 0 (2^512, 155 digits, with the extra bit representing the sign)? OR should I be using decimal?

Comment: There is no difference between `numeric` and `decimal`

Comment: `numeric(78)` would be the way to go.

Comment: Excellent question. This is very relevant when dealing with Ethereum since that blockchain uses uint256 for many different things such as transferred amount and asset IDs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`numeric(78,0)` has a max value of 9.999... * 10^77 > 2^256 so that is sufficient.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a domain.

```
CREATE DOMAIN uint_256 AS NUMERIC NOT NULL
CHECK (VALUE >= 0 AND VALUE < 2^256)
CHECK (SCALE(VALUE) = 0)
```

This creates a reusable `uint_256` datatype which is constrained to be within the `2^256` limit and also prevents rounding errors by only allowing the scale of the number to be 0 (i.e. throws an error with decimal values). There is nothing like `NULL` in Solidity so the datatype should not be nullable.

Try it: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b6672d3946762e79eb75ed996abb3d6b)

Comment: This approach has the benefit of making the intent more understandable. Looking at a table definition with an amount column, `amount uint256`  is easier to understand than `numeric(78,0)`.
You can find some drawbacks of using domains here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/152859/what-are-the-drawbacks-of-using-domains-to-store-metadata-about-the-column