# How to use postgres to cast a 64-char / 256-bit hex-string to a numeric(78,0)?

Tags: postgresql, casting, hex

Trying to translate a uint256 number which is encoded as a 64-char / 256-bit hex.
Eventually the result should be stored in a numeric(78,0) which is [enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50072618/how-to-create-an-uint256-in-postgresql) to encode an uint256.

For smaller hex-strings there's pretty direct ways to encode to int4/int8 but this won't do here.

Therefore trying to chunk the hex up in 4 64-bit parts, which can all be represented by a int8. Then glue it up with some bitshifting and done.

Unfortunately didn't realise int8 is signed so that gives me wrong results (code below).
I guess I could chunk the hex up in smaller parts and make it work with a lot of hassle, but by now I'm wondering that there must somehow be a better way. Anyone?

```
-- 1. Split 256 bits into 4 seperate parts which are represented by int8's which can all hold 64 bits (4 * 64 = 256)
-- 2. cast int8 to numeric(78,0) which can hold a uint256, and some bitshifting (but not really since not supported by numeric) to get all parts
-- 3. add up the parts to arrive at the final number
--
-- WRONG RESULT: since int8 are signed. 
select 
 val_a + val_b + val_c + val_d as value  
from(
     select 
        -- concat('x', substr(value, 0, 64))::bit(256) value_as_bits, -- all data as 256 bits
        concat('x', substr(value, 0, 16))::bit(64)::int8::numeric(78,0) * 2^48::numeric(78,0) val_a,
        concat('x', substr(value, 0 + 16, 16))::bit(64)::int8::numeric(78,0) * 2^32::numeric(78,0) val_b,
        concat('x', substr(value, 0 + 32, 16))::bit(64)::int8::numeric(78,0) * 2^16::numeric(78,0) val_c, 
        concat('x', substr(value, 0 + 48, 16))::bit(64)::int8::numeric(78,0) val_d -- '-8257646570878140416' issue here since int8 is not unsigned
    from (
        select '000000000000000000000000000000000000000015b19218d66f231d61600000' as value -- hex representation of an unsigned 256 bit number
    ) as x
 
) as x;
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question:

```
-- Val is 64-char hex. Transform to Uint256 represented as a numeric(78,0)
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uint256_hash_to_numeric (val text) RETURNS numeric AS $$ 
    select val_a + val_b + val_c + val_d + val_e
    from(
         select 
            concat('x00000000', substr(value, 1, 8))::bit(64)::int8::numeric(78,0) * 2^224::numeric(78,0) val_a,
            concat('x00', substr(value, 9, 14))::bit(64)::int8::numeric(78,0) * 2^168::numeric(78,0) val_b,
            concat('x00', substr(value, 23, 14))::bit(64)::int8::numeric(78,0) * 2^112::numeric(78,0) val_c,
            concat('x00', substr(value, 37, 14))::bit(64)::int8::numeric(78,0) * 2^56::numeric(78,0) val_d,
            concat('x00', substr(value, 51, 14))::bit(64)::int8::numeric(78,0) val_e 
        from (select val as value) as x
    ) as x
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

I'll be performance testing this and will leave open in the meantime

Answer (score 2):

## Introduction

You can do something like

```
('x'||lpad(the_hex_value,16,'0'))::bit(64)::bigint
```

The following sections will cover cases when even `bigint` would not be enough.

## Sample schema

```
create table temp(
    pk serial primary key,
    ch char(1),
    fk int,
    ind int
);

insert into temp(ch, fk)
select unnest(
    string_to_array(
        regexp_replace('0123456789ABCD', E'(.)(?!$)', E'\\1 ', 'g'),
        ' '
    )
), 1;

insert into temp(ch, fk)
select unnest(
    string_to_array(
        regexp_replace('123', E'(.)(?!$)', E'\\1 ', 'g'),
        ' '
    )
), 2;


update temp tmp
set ind = (select count(*) from temp tmp2 where tmp2.fk = tmp.fk and tmp2.pk > tmp.pk);
```

Explanation:

- we create a table called `temp`

  - `pk` is a `primary key` which will be useful later to determine the position of each digit
  - `ch` is a char representing the hexa digit
  - `fk` is a foreign key, a one-way vertex towards the original table
  - `ind` is an initially uninitialized field, which will turn out to be the inverted digit index in order to be able to determine which power of 16 should we multiply the numeric value of `ch` with
- we fill this `temp` table with two rows, using some hard-coded values in our example both for the actual hexa number and the foreign key
- we update `temp` in order to compute and store the appropriate value of `ind`

## The query

```
select fk, sum(digit)
from (
select fk, case
    when ch = 'A' then 10
    when ch = 'B' then 11
    when ch = 'C' then 12
    when ch = 'D' then 13
    when ch = 'E' then 14
    when ch = 'F' then 15
    else ch::int
end
* power(16, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ind) - 1) as digit
from temp) t
group by fk;
```

Explanation:

- we convert `ch` into a numerical value
- and multiply it with 16^(one less than the inverted index)
- we group by `fk` in order to make sure that we get the individual value for each `fk`
- finally we `sum` the computed representative digit value for each `fk` group

Note, here we sum the values. If you experience any problems with this, feel free to convert the digits into textual and concat them with `string_agg`. **You should aim to the simpler approach if possible and resort to this one only if any easier approach fails.**

Comment: Nice. Would have never thoughts about this. Would that actually be faster than what I'm doing?

Comment: @Geert-Jan probably not, because my code is not using the inbuilt features directly. I would not exclude it, so it is worth doing some benchmarking to compare performances if performance is of primary concern. The main point of this answer is that you can convert your hexa into a `bigint` and in general I would do that when possible. If not possible, then you will need to implement a solution for yourself and the approach I have explained is such a fallback approach. Have you tried (and perhaps succeeded) using the `bigint` conversion?

Comment: unfortunately a uint256 (which is a given) is 32 bytes so would require 4 bigints. Otherwise, I agree there would be easier methods.